# BigQuery filtering records in standard sql

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm working on counting all visitors that submitted postcode on our homepage. I came up with following query in legacy SQL:

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitStartTime
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-01-29'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
where hits.page.pagePath = '/broadband/'
and visitStartTime > 1483228800
and hits.type   = 'EVENT'
and hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Homepage'
and hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Submit Postcode';
```

I then wanted to convert it to standard SQL to use within CTE and came up with this one that doesn't seem right though.

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitStartTime
FROM ``ga_sessions_*``, UNNEST(hits) as h
where 

_TABLE_SUFFIX > '2017-01-29'
AND h.page.pagePath = '/broadband/'
and visitStartTime > 1483228800
and h.type  = 'EVENT'
and h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Homepage'
and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Submit Postcode';
```

The first one processes 327 MB and returns 4117 results, the second one processes 6.98 GB and returns 60745 results.

I've looked at the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#filtering_repeated_fields), but it didn't prove very helpful for me.

ga_sessions has [standard schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) of GA import into Bigquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like difference is coming from the fact that with Standard SQL you are flattening the table on `hits` when you `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits)` in the `FROM` clause, and therefore adding more rows to the result. More equivalent query would be:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitStartTime
FROM `ga_sessions_*`
where 
_TABLE_SUFFIX > '20170129'   
and visitStartTime > 1483228800
and EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) h 
  WHERE h.type  = 'EVENT'
    and h.page.pagePath = '/broadband/'
    and h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Homepage'
    and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Submit Postcode');
```

Comment: exists subquery is not joined to anything? in what cases wouldn't it be true?

Comment: I moved the pagePath predicate to subquery where h is available. 4699 results,  2.84 GB processed. 

Is _TABLE_SUFFIX > '20170129'   and 

parse_date("%Y%m%d", regexp_extract(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) >=  parse_date("%Y-%m-%d", '2017-01-29')

equivalent?

Comment: I suggest you first test your query on one specific date, so you take _TABLE_SUFFIX predicate out of the query. Once you get matching numbers on one day, need to find the equivalent _TABLE_SUFFIX condition, although the one I put in the query looks the same as in your original query.

Comment: EXISTS semijoins on UNNEST(hits) - same as CROSS JOIN on UNNEST(hits) that you had in your original query.

Comment: For single day I get matching results! Thanks! I'll accept your answer. I still don't fully understand the differences and I'll have to read up more.

Answer (score 1):

What happened here is that as `_TABLE_SUFFIX` is a string so when you do:

```
_TABLE_SUFFIX > '2017-01-29'
```

You will end up selecting way more tables then expected as string comparisons is different from number comparisons.

One possible way to fix that is by parsing the string to `DATE` type:

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitStartTime
FROM `ga_sessions*`, UNNEST(hits) as h
where parse_date("%Y%m%d", regexp_extract(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)')) >=  parse_date("%Y-%m-%d", '2017-01-29')

AND h.page.pagePath = '/broadband/'
and visitStartTime > 1483228800
and h.type  = 'EVENT'
and h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Homepage'
and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Submit Postcode';
```

Where the [parse_date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date) operation first casts the string to `DATE` and then the comparison is made.

Notice as well that I changed the wildcard selection to **ga_sessions** and then using the `REGEX_EXTRACT` I consider only what comes after the "_" character. By doing so, you'll be able to select "intraday" tables as well.

Comment: I've fixed some likely typos in your answer and the results are now way closer although still not the same. 

They both now process the same amount of data suggesting that same tabels are searched. (I don't think I have up-to-date intraday tables in the namespace.) 

There are still differences though: the standard sql runs for 17.3s and returns 7749 results. The legacy sql runs for 1.4s and returns 6623 results...

Comment: hmm I see. Could you please add this condition: `and not regexp_contains(_table_suffix, r'intraday')` in the `WHERE` clause and see if results match? I'm suspecting that the intradays tables are adding a few more rows that the legacy didn't consider before.

Comment: It hasn't changed results.

My understanding that we copy only the full day results to a namespace in the EU region. This is the namespace I query so it wouldn't have intraday results.

Is it expected the standard sql to take much longer?