# Can't translate custom GA segment to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently trying to write the following custom segment from GA in Bigquery:
GA Segment
[image: GA Segment]

I wrote the following code but it is generating different numbers than GA:

```
SELECT date,
sum(new_visits) as new_visits
FROM
(SELECT date, 
first_session_login,
first_session_email,
landing_page_customer,
first_session_cms_referral,
new_visits
FROM
(SELECT
date, 
case when visitNumber = 1 and hits.page.pagePath like '/login%' then 1 else 0 end as first_session_login,
case when visitNumber = 1 and trafficSource.medium = 'email' then 1 else 0 end as first_session_email,
case when visitNumber = 1 and hits.isEntrance is true and REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath, r'/support/.*|/app/.*|/billing/.*|/goal/.*|/login/.*|/signup-flow/.*') is true then 1 else 0 end as landing_page_customer,
case when visitNumber = 1 and trafficSource.medium = 'cms referral' then 1 else 0 end as first_session_cms_referral,
totals.newVisits as new_visits
FROM
(SELECT
  date, visitNumber, hits.page.pagePath, trafficSource.medium, hits.isEntrance, hits.type, hits.hitNumber, geoNetwork.country, totals.newVisits
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([81532559.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'))))
)
WHERE 
first_session_login = 0
AND 
first_session_email = 0
AND 
landing_page_customer = 0
AND 
first_session_cms_referral = 0)
GROUP BY date
```

What is wrong in my code? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's easy to end up overcounting when using legacy SQL due to implicit "flattening". Here's an example showing how to avoid flattening using an EXISTS clause with standard SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41977310/6253347

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the [Standard Version](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), this might work for you:

```
SELECT
  date,
  COUNT(1) new_visits
FROM `dataset_id.ga_sessions*`
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND CASE WHEN (REGEXP_CONTAINS(_table_suffix, 'intraday') AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)') BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) THEN TRUE
           WHEN (NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(_table_suffix, 'intraday') AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)') BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) THEN TRUE END
  AND totals.visits = 1
  AND totals.newVisits = 1
  AND NOT trafficSource.medium IN ('email', 'cms referral')
  AND NOT EXISTS(select 1 from UNNEST(hits) where REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'$/login') OR (isEntrance and REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'/support/.*|/app/.*|/billing/.*|/goal/.*|/login/.*|/signup-flow/.*')))
GROUP BY
  date
```

As Elliott pointed out, working with Legacy is a bit harder as it already flattens all arrays automatically. In Standard SQL, running this type of analyzes is quite straightforward.